# How to get all categories using REST API without any login or token in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Using Admin Token categories will comes in rest API but without token not working any solution on to how to get all categories without token in magento 2

Comment: What do you mean by token? Are you using any OAuth or something? Could you add a little more details please.

Comment: Why do you need it without token, it is always better to be authenticated for Api.

Comment: Without oAuth i want to get all categories and products it is possible in magento2?

Comment: Yes it is better to authenticated for Api but in mobile app without Login Customer How to display categories and products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Magento 2 allows access without authentication for few endpoints, which are declared as `anonymous` resources. For example, `V1/directory/currency` and `V1/directory/countries` can be accessed without any authentication.

But, When Users need to access to non-anonymous endpoints. This option (`Allow Anonymous Guest Access`) must be enabled:

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security > Allow Anonymous Guest Access
```

Now, It is possible to get the categories without authentication by using this endpoint.

```
http://example.com/rest/V1/categories
```

**Note:** It is not recommended to use Magento 2 REST API without authentication.